# How to hide an element or div if a string is null?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, dom

I have a website that uses server-generated JSON objects to populate its content. I want to implement optional text descriptions for images which only appear if an image has a description. I tried to do this by assigning the description contained in a JSON object to a string and checking if the string equals "null" or not, but this didn't work. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<p id="image-description"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Note: I'm not trying to populate the innerHTML of <p> with the content 
// of `descriptionString` here 

// At beginning of script:
var descriptionString = ''

// Inside function that populates website with content from JSON object:
parsedJSON = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

descriptionString = parsedJSON['activities'][0]['description'];
if (descriptionString != 'null') {
    document.getElementById('image-description').style.display = 'block';
} else {
    document.getElementById('image-description').style.display = 'none';
}
```

The `image-description` element always appears with this code, even when `descriptionString` is `'null'`. I also tried using `.style.visibility = 'visible';` and `.style.visibility = 'hidden';` as well as putting the element in a div, but they all produced the same result. Moreover, when I set a default style for `image-description` with CSS and tried to modify it with JavaScript it wouldn't change.

I've confirmed that the string from `parsedJSON` is being properly assigned to `descriptionString` (and assigns `'null'` when no string is present) so I must be doing something else wrong.

I haven't found any other answers that address this exact scenario, and I am trying not to use external libraries like jQuery. What is the best way to solve this with pure JavaScript?

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the value of the JSON property is `'null'` and not `null`? There's a world of difference between the string value `"null"` and the actual value `null`.

Comment: Including your JSON, or a representative sample, would probably be very helpful.

Comment: Can you show the JSON file?

Comment: add console.log(descriptionString) before if(...!='null') and then try calling the portions inside the if blocks from the console. That should tell you whether you are simply not able to set the style correctly or whether JDB's comment is the root cause. Also, if you're setting the style on page load, check that something else isn't resetting it after the fact. You can right click and check the current style by selecting 'inspect element' in any browser. Last thing to check is that another element isn't overriding the visibility with another css tag with !important  for example.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that the value is `'null'` instead of `null` for 3 reasons: 1.) when "null" is assigned to the description column for an entry in my database it appears to be treated as a string, 2.) when I changed my code to check if `descriptionString != 'a-different-string-from-the-database'` the same error occurred, and 3.) the Java version of the code in my post worked perfectly when I built an android app that receives the exact same JSON from the server.

Comment: Actually, the commenters here were right: the JSON really was sending `null` instead of `'null'`. I didn't think this was the case because I experienced an error when I initially tried to treat the response as `null`, but I just realized that the error was caused by something else. My code works now -- thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try to understand the difference between `null` & `'null'`.

**null :** null is used to represent the absence of some value.

```js
descriptionString = null;
if (descriptionString != null) {
    document.getElementById('image-description').style.display = 'block';
} else {
    document.getElementById('image-description').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div id="image-description">
Image 
</div>
```

**'null' :** `''` represent a string in JavaScript.

```js
descriptionString = 'null';
if (descriptionString != null) {
    document.getElementById('image-description').style.display = 'block';
} else {
    document.getElementById('image-description').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div id="image-description">
Image 
</div>
```

Comment: This was the answer. I actually understood this difference already but thought my server was sending a string called 'null' instead of a null value due to the way a different part of my program responded to the server output. I figured out that the other part of my program was converting all server responses to strings without me realizing it and the actual value is null (e.g. no value).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an = in your comparison, and also remove the quotes (unless you compare against a string).

```
if (descriptionString !== null)
```

Comment: Adding an extra `=` is good practice, but it's almost certainly not the source of the OP's issue. Also, we have yet to establish whether or not the JSON property's value is `null` or the actual string `"null"`, so this advice might be wrong.

Comment: @JDB True, just wanted to be sure to get that type comparison to.

Comment: I already tried this before posting and it wasn't the source of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

you have an error in your code .just missed  a semicolon in descrition and check whether element is empty or initialize variable to null. below is the snippet to prove

```
var descriptionString = '';

// Inside function that populates website with content from JSON object:
parsedJSON = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

descriptionString = parsedJSON['activities'][0]['description'];
if (descriptionString != '') {
    document.getElementById('image-description').style.display = 'block';
} else {
    document.getElementById('image-description').style.display = 'none';
}
```

> In JavaScript null is "nothing". It is supposed to be something that
>   doesn't exist.
>
> Unfortunately, in JavaScript, the data type of null is an object.
>
> You can consider it a bug in JavaScript that typeof null is an object.
>    It should be null.

correct one:

```html
<p>An empty string has both a legal value and a type:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var car = null;
if(car ==null)
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="The value is: " +car + "<br>" +"The type is: " + typeof car;
</script>
```

wrong one:

```html
<p>An empty string has both a legal value and a type:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var car = '';
if(car ==null)
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="The value is: " +car + "<br>" +"The type is: " + typeof car;
</script>
```

Comment: I actually just found the source of the issue thanks to another commenter. I thought my server was sending a string called `'null'` but it was actually just sending `null`. So the problem was similar to what you suggested but not the same.

Comment: any time happy coding:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 if (!descriptionString.trim()||descriptionString.trim().length == 0) {
         document.getElementById('image-
       description').style.display = 'none';
      }
      else
      {
    document.getElementById('image-description').style.display = 'block';
      }
```

Remember   String value "null" and normal null value are not same.keep that difference in mind while debugging